# nfs export to ipv6 client

Tags: nfs, ipv6

My NFS exports are accessible via IPv4 to a number of hosts on my LAN.

I want to make these exports available via IPv6 so that I can mount them to my laptop when I'm away. When I'm away I can access these LAN hosts via their IPv6 address and from them can access my laptop via its IPv6 address.

So I assume that the blocking issue is in the NFS configuration somewhere.

So here is a line from the server's `/etc/exports`:

```
/export/test 2001:123:a:b:c:d:e:f(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

where that IPv6 address is the laptop's network device through which I can ping from the NFS server, open a SSH session...

And here is the corresponding line from the client's `/etc/fstab`

```
[2604:123:c:d:e:f]:/export/test /mnt/test nfs nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.device-ut=10 0 0
```

For the IPv6 address I have tried `[address]` `'[address]'` and simply `address`.

But in all cases, attempting to mount returns the error

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting `address`:/export/test
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer is: Do use "aliases".

Instead of typing the address (all the hassle with syntax) you define it in /etc/hosts. The proper old school way.

In /etc/hosts you define the (IPv6) address - name.domain pair. 
And/or the address(IPv6) - name pair. 
Use the same name.domain (or just name) for IPv4 and "constant" IPv6 addresses in /etc/hosts. IPv6 is friendly: In /etc/hosts just give several addresses to the same (alias-)name.

The laptop has wifi and ethernet? Give ALL "constant" addresses to one name in /etc/hosts! This solves the problem of different interface - addresses!

Example :

```
/etc/hosts
fdc5:d54e:dca5:0:8db6:d5f5:86d0:6bd9   lause lause.simulacron lause6  lause6wlan
fdc5:d54e:dca5:0:f051:d54e:dca5:cc43   lause lause.simulacron lause6  lause6ether
192.168.71.234   lause lause.simulacron lause4wlan
192.168.72.234   lause lause.simulacron lause4ether
```

Alias is not a good word but it may show the gist: 
In /etc/hosts you do not have issues with the syntax / notation. 
Moreover you can define several addresses that are tried in a row by mount.nfs for example.

Next you do not use [fd....] notation in your mount. You just use the name.domain (or just  name) instead.

Put the mount config into /etc/fstab if used again later. There are more options on offer.

---

A word about "constant" IPv6 addresses: 
Static IP is great for IPv4. 
Static IPv6 is stupid, in most cases. A smart solution is NOT to use static IPv6.

Use  Prefix Delegation
and / or 
you just use the ULA addresses (just both in parallel and for both interfaces!).

Most versatile solution is to combine EUI64 + "privacy extensions". 
You can simply calculate the ULA (like a fixed IP!) but other people from the outside see random addresses (randomness better than NAT). 
Having PD + ULA in place solves all needs of privacy and constant, reliable, predictable addresses - in IPv6.

This is an abbreviated description derived from my existing network. It may contain errors. Or is specific for my Linux distro (Ubuntu 20.04). Please let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: If static IPv6 is not recommended what is the purpose of IPV6 DNS. Also: Rather than saying "X is stupid" please explain the situation so that readers of your post understand why X is not a good strategy.